# How to initialize web-app constants (from a text file) upon Tomcat startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, configuration

I have deployed a web application on my local Tomcat 7. This web-app needs to know the location of three folders.

Here is what that code looks like at the moment:

```
public class Constants {

    public enum Folder {

        InboundFolder("C:\\inbound\\"),
        StagingFolder("C:\\staging\\"),
        OutboundFolder("C:\\outbound\\");

        private String location;

        private Folder(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public String locate() {
            return location;
        }
    }

    // ...and so on...
```

I don't want to hard-code the values; instead, I want to load the values of those constants from a text source when I start up my Tomcat 7. I've read about `ServletConfig` and `ServletContext` but I'm not sure if they're the solutions to what I want.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Why you don;t want to keep it in context ?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to keep it in context. My code is what it is now, because I don't know what's the best approach to doing this. I'll take whichever is most straightforward.

Comment: put them in servlet context or use properties file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have many choices how to init your constants. There are two common ways

**1) Init parameters.**

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.MyServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>myParam</param-name>
        <param-value>paramValue</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

MyServlet.java

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected String s;

    @Override 
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException{
        super(servletConfig);
        this.s = servletConfig.getInitParameter("myParam");
    }

    ....

}
```

**2) Config file**

You should create properties file in you app, in src folder for example config.properties

```
myParam=paramValue
```

Config.java

```
public class Config {

    private Properties config;

    public Config() {
        config = new Properties();
        reloadConfig();
    }

    public Properties getConfig(){
        reloadConfig();
        return config;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key){
        return getConfig().getProperty(key);
    }

    public void reloadConfig() {

            try {
                config.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyServlet.java

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected Config config = new Config();

    @Override 
    public void doGet(request, response) throws ServletException{

        Strign s = config.getProperty("myParam");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the first approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public static Object myDataStaticObject=null;

...

if (myDataStaticObject==null) {
    File file= new File("C:\\inbound\\", "myCfg.properties");
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(stream);
    //set your data to myDataStaticObject
}
```

Load your data in an static object & check if it's null to load for first time.

Think about directory permissions in your production server!

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to address your concerns.

`1`. Use serveltContext
  web.xml entries

> ```
>   <context-param>
>          <param-name>file1</param-name>
>          <param-value>file1-location</param-value>
>       </context-param>
>       <context-param>
>          <param-name>file2</param-name>
>          <param-value>file2-location</param-value>
>       </context-param>
> ```

and fetch these values at runtime when you need.

`2`. Use properties file and load that properties file and access those properties using accessor method.

`3`. Use XML base configuration and parse and keep it in memory. (You can also use WatchServices so you can reload file if it changed)

`4`. Supply your file locations as runtime argument while starting application server(least preffered)

> -Dfile1=FILE1-LOCATION -Dfile2=FILE2-LOCATION